# SQL join two tables on subsets of data

Tags: sql, join, outer-join

I have two tables in the following format:

### TABLE 1

```
data_1      | data_2     |  weight  
 1          |   a        | 25   
 1          |   b        | 25 
 1          |   c        | 25 
 1          |   d        | 25 
 2          |   e        | 100
```

### TABLE 2

```
data_4     | data_1     | data_2     | value
 AB        | 1          | a          | 25 
 AB        | 1          | b          | 25 
 AB        | 1          | c          | 25 
 AB        | 1          | d          | 25 
 BC        | 2          | e          | 50 
 BC        | 2          | f          | 50 
 CD        | 1          | a          | 50 
 CD        | 1          | b          | 50
```

I am looking to create the following output:

### OUTPUT

```
data_4     | data_1     | data_2    | value    | weight
 AB        | 1          | a         | 25       | 25 
 AB        | 1          | b         | 25       | 25
 AB        | 1          | c         | 25       | 25
 AB        | 1          | d         | 25       | 25
 BC        | 2          | e         | 50       | 100
 BC        | 2          | f         | 50       | 0
 CD        | 1          | a         | 50       | 25
 CD        | 1          | b         | 50       | 25
 CD        | 1          | c         | 0          | 25
 CD        | 1          | d         | 0          | 25
```

Essentially I am looking to join the tables on data_1 and data_2 for each data_4 record whilst showing value and weight with their corresponding values.

I tried a couple of things but don't seem to be getting the correct output. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: give what you have tried so far

Comment: (1) Tag with the database you are using.  (2) Why do new rows appear for CD but not BC?

Comment: Because in Table 2 you can see that BC falls into [data_1] type 2 and within that is holding [data_2] type e & type f. The target for a [data_1] type 2 is to hold [data_2] e only. Therefore the output table shows BC still as [data_1] type 2 and shows it holding [data_2] e & f with value of 50 and 50 respectively but with weight (target weights) of 100 and 0 respectively.

Comment: CD however is [data_1] type 1 and has current holdings of [data_2] type a & b. A [data_1] type 1 has a target of holding [data_2] a,b,c,d each with weight of 25. Therefore it should show [data_2] c&d along with its current holding in [data_2] a &b.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, this is quite complicated.  The hard part (in my opinion) is getting the right `data_4` in the first column -- a `full join` would produce `null` values.

The following approach takes all rows from `table_2` and matches to `table_1` using a `left join`.  It then adds in the remaining rows that the `left join` does not include:

```
select t2.data_4, t2.data_1, t2.data_2, t2.value, coalesce(t1.weight, 0) as weight
from table2 t2 left join
     table1 t1
     using (data_1, data_2)
union all
select t2.data_4, t1.data_1, t1.data_2, t2.value, t1.weight
from table_1 t1 cross join
     (select distinct t2.data_4 from table2 t2) d4 left join
     table_2 t2
     on t2.data_4 = d4.data_4 and
        t2.data_1 = t1.data_1 and 
        t2.data_2 = t1.data_2
where t2.data_4 is null;
```

EDIT:

Hmmm . . . I think there might a slightly simpler approach:

```
select t41.data_4, t41.data_1, t2.data_2,
       coalesce(t2.value, 0) as value,
       coalesce(t1.weight, 0) as weight
from (select distinct t2.data_4, t2.data_1 from table_2 t2) d41 left join
     table_1 t1
     on t1.data_1 = t41.data_1 left join
     table_2 t2
     on t2.data_4 = t41.data_4 and
        t2.data_1 = t41.data_1 and
        (t2.data_2 = t1.data_2 or t1.data_1 is null);
```

Comment: Yes, a full join doesn't add the additional data_2 items from table 1. I think the above looks good but I am getting an error for using dr.?

Comment: When I run the first of the above I am getting NULL results in data_4 when these should all be populated. Two of the NULLS seem to be replicating the BC - 2 - e weight = 1 row but excluding the data_4 (BC) when there should only be one record of BC with data_1 = 2 and data_2 = e.

Comment: I can't seem to run script 2 - it isn't picking up t41.[data_1],  t41.[data_4], t2.[data_4] or t2.[data_1].